# Convergence on $(a,b)$ but not on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n(x)\to 0$ point-wise on $(a,b)$, but that $f_n(x)$ does not converge to any function when $x=a$ or $x=b$, because $f_n(x)$ oscillates at these points.

Further, suppose that $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$ on $[a,b]$.

In this case, is it still correct to say $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf_n(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^b\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\mathrm{d}x=0\ ?$$

I know we have almost everywhere convergence, however I am not sure about the above equality since $f_n(x)$ doesn't converge *at all* when $x=a$ or $x=b$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know.  I asked a follow up question afterwards for clarification, but I never heard back you (see below).  This is why I originally didn't accept your answer.

Comment: My bad, I hadn't seen the edited version of your comment.

Comment: No worries, thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it is the case. *(Assuming your $g$ is integrable, of course.)*

Define $(\tilde{f}_n)_n$ by setting
$$\tilde{f}_n(x) = \begin{cases}
f_n(x) & x\in(a,b)\\
0 & x\in\{a,b\}
\end{cases}$$
Then, $(\tilde{f}_n)_n$ does still converge pointwise to $0$,, and we still have $\lvert \tilde{f}_n(x)\rvert \leq g(x)$ for all $n\geq 0$ and $x\in[a,b]$. So we can use the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) on $(\tilde{f}_n)_n$ to get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_a^b \tilde{f}_n = \int_a^b \lim_{n\to\infty } f_n = 0.
$$

It only remains to observe that for all $n\geq 0$, $\int_a^b f_n = \int_a^b \tilde{f}_n$ to conclude that, for all $n\geq 0$,
$$
\int_a^b f_n = \int_a^b \tilde{f}_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer--this seems to make sense.  To make sure that I understand: the last equality could be written more precisely as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b\tilde{f}_n=\int_a^b\lim_{n\to\infty}\tilde{f}_n=0$.  This follows since $\int_a^bf_n=\int_a^b\tilde{f}_n$.  Is this thinking correct?

Comment: @runner.87 You're welcome!

Comment: @runner.87 Arf, I hadn't seen the edited version of your comment. Yes, this is correct. (You can also think of it as "the two sequences of integrals are equal, so in particular so are their limits.")